# Powershell self remove after script run

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to delete the script after it ran but I'm getting an error saying the file is in use, what can I do?

```
$exclude = @("*.zip", "*.dll", "*.exe")
Get-ChildItem "C:\.." -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -WhatIf

Remove-Item $PSScriptRoot -Force
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, `$PSScriptRoot` is the *directory* where the script is located. Assuming PowerShell 3, you should use `$PSCommandPath` to call the full path of the script:

```
Remove-Item $PSCommandPath -Force
```

Comment: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty 
string.

Comment: Hmm odd, if I run it in ISE I'm getting an error, if I run the script by rightclick>run with PS it works, thanks

Answer (score 4):

`$PSScriptRoot` is not pointing to the script, but rather the directory it's in. Try `Remove-Item $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Force`

Answer (score 1):

I would simple copy the script to temp directory, delete original and run it from temp.

```
Copy-Item -Path .\myscript.ps1 -Destination $env:TEMP\myscript.ps1

$env:TEMP\myscript.ps1

Remove-Item -Path .\myscript.ps1
```